# Centos пропали базы данных(

Tags: mysql, centos, администрирование

Изначально на сервере были:

```
mysql-libs-5.1.52-1.el6_0.1.x86_64
mysql-server-5.1.52-1.el6_0.1.x86_64
mysql-5.1.52-1.el6_0.1.x86_64
php-mysql-5.3.3-23.el6_4.x86_64
```

Погуглил статью как обновить mysql и вбил строку:

```
yum -y update mysql*
```

И все базы исчезли!(( Как их можно восстановить? 10 сайтов умерло ... 
Сейчас показывает:

```
mysql-5.1.73-7.el6.x86_64
mysql-libs-5.1.73-7.el6.x86_64
mysql-server-5.1.73-7.el6.x86_64
php-mysql-5.3.3-47.el6.x86_64
```

Содержимое у файлов my.cnf и my.cnf.orig одинаковые:

```
# Example MySQL config file for small systems.
#
# This is for a system with little memory (<= 64M) where MySQL is only used
# from time to time and it's important that the mysqld daemon
# doesn't use much resources.
#
# MySQL programs look for option files in a set of
# locations which depend on the deployment platform.
# You can copy this option file to one of those
# locations. For information about these locations, see:
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/option-files.html
#
# In this file, you can use all long options that a program supports.
# If you want to know which options a program supports, run the program
# with the "--help" option.

# The following options will be passed to all MySQL clients
[client]
#password   = your_password
port        = 3306
socket      = /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

# Here follows entries for some specific programs

# The MySQL server
[mysqld]
port        = 3306
socket      = /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
skip-locking
key_buffer_size = 16K
max_allowed_packet = 1M
table_open_cache = 4
sort_buffer_size = 64K
read_buffer_size = 256K
read_rnd_buffer_size = 256K
net_buffer_length = 2K
thread_stack = 128K

# Don't listen on a TCP/IP port at all. This can be a security enhancement,
# if all processes that need to connect to mysqld run on the same host.
# All interaction with mysqld must be made via Unix sockets or named pipes.
# Note that using this option without enabling named pipes on Windows
# (using the "enable-named-pipe" option) will render mysqld useless!
# 
#skip-networking
server-id   = 1

# Uncomment the following if you want to log updates
#log-bin=mysql-bin

# binary logging format - mixed recommended
#binlog_format=mixed

# Uncomment the following if you are using InnoDB tables
#innodb_data_home_dir = /var/lib/mysql
#innodb_data_file_path = ibdata1:10M:autoextend
#innodb_log_group_home_dir = /var/lib/mysql
# You can set .._buffer_pool_size up to 50 - 80 %
# of RAM but beware of setting memory usage too high
#innodb_buffer_pool_size = 16M
#innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 2M
# Set .._log_file_size to 25 % of buffer pool size
#innodb_log_file_size = 5M
#innodb_log_buffer_size = 8M
#innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 1
#innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 50

[mysqldump]
quick
max_allowed_packet = 16M

[mysql]
no-auto-rehash
# Remove the next comment character if you are not familiar with SQL
#safe-updates

[myisamchk]
key_buffer_size = 8M
sort_buffer_size = 8M

[mysqlhotcopy]
interactive-timeout
```

Comment: Видимо, поменялись пути к данным БД, а конфиги не обновились. Пропишите путь к данным.

Comment: приложите к вопросу вывод команды `$ grep -r datadir /etc/mysql*`. исправить вопрос можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin grep: /etc/mysql: No such file or directory

Comment: @ilyaplot, подскажи как их прописать ?

Comment: @user213645, прошу прощения, не уточнил, как в *centos* конф. файлы называются. замените, пожалуйста, `mysql*` на `my*`, чтобы команда звучала: `$ grep -r datadir /etc/my*`

Comment: @alexanderbarakin , увы при наборе команды ничего не происходит (

Comment: @user213645, хм. а файлы вообще такие есть? `$ ls -l /etc/my*`

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, /etc/my.cnf
 /etc/my.cnf.0.orig

Comment: @user213645, отлично! приведите, пожалуйста, в вопросе содержимое обоих этих файлов.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, готово

Comment: @user213645, мда. никаких наводок. попробуем угадать. в каталоге `/var/lib/mysql/` не присутствуют каталоги с названиями ваших баз данных? если нет, попробуйте поискать: `$ sudo find /var -name имя`, где `имя` — имя какой-нибудь из ваших баз данных.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, да нашел, в /var/lib/mysql.1466688090/ ........ РЕШИЛ СПАСИБО ОГРОМНОЕ)))

Comment: @user213645, дата в имени каталога намекает, что он был переименован примерно за 25 минут до того, как вы написали вопрос. попробуйте указать этот каталог как datadir в файле `/etc/my.cnf` в секции `[mysqld]` и перезапустить после этого mysqld: `datadir = /var/lib/mysql.1466688090`

Comment: @user213645, selinux у вас, кстати, не включен ли? если да, то без изменения контекста этих файлов/каталогов у mysqld будут проблемы с доступом к ним. проверить статус selinux-а: `$ sudo sestatus`

Comment: Не хочу сыпать соль на рану, но надо было делать бэкапы.

Comment: *РЕШИЛ СПАСИБО* — напишите, пожалуйста, ответ с изложением вашего решения. вполне вероятно, что эта информация будет полезна ещё кому-нибудь.

Answer (score 1):

*Ответ из комментариев*

Файлы баз данных хранятся в каталоге данных, поэтому, чтобы не случилось - СУБД не видит базы, таблицы, бинарные файлы следует искать следует по пути /var/lib/mysql/.